# How to enable peek and pop in iOS WebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios9, 3dtouch

I'm loading my website in an UIWebView in my iOS app.
How can I enable peek and pop (3d touch) for the links in the WebView?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

According to the most recent Apple docs you can enable peek and pop in a UIWebView with the `allowLinkPreview` option. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/allowsLinkPreview

The trick with that option is that it only pops into Safari and the docs state you cannot get around that. If you want the peek and pop to stay within your app you need to consider using SFSafariViewController but you lose control over your users web view experience.